# How to test pending flag in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, jasmine, angular-test

I have `fetchBooks` method that retrieve data from backend and then populates `books` variable.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  isLoading: boolean;
  books;

  constructor(private booksService: BooksService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.fetchBooks();
  }

  fetchBooks(): void {
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.booksService
      .fetchBooks()
      .subscribe(
        response => {
          this.isLoading = false;
          this.books = response.data;
          // ..
        },
        error => {
          this.isLoading = false;
          // ..
        }
      );
  }
}
```

I need to write unit tests for `isLoading` flag. I wrote something like this

```
it('should work', async () => {
  sut.fetchBooks();

  // ...
  expect(sut.isLoading).toBe(true);
  // ...
  expect(sut.isLoading).toBe(false);
});
```

But I struggle with the rest. Maybe someone knows how to solve it or knows some article that explains it?

Comment: Is `fetchBooks` method a component method? Please provide complete, minimal code.

Comment: yes, it is a component method! I have updated the example

Comment: https://medium.com/@paynoattn/simple-observable-unit-testing-in-angular2-43c4f4a0bfe2

Comment: @bubbles thanks for sharing the article, but I don't think it explains how to test the pending state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is to make use of a [Subject](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/subject) to control the emission of values. Pass `subject.asObservable()` to the spy which your SUT is subscribing to.

```js
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

it('should correctly work', () => {
  // replace SomeType with the type returned by booksService.fetchData()
  const subject = new Subject<SomeType>();
  spyOn(booksService, 'fetchData').and.returnValue(subject.asObservable());
  const mockData: SomeType = {}; // put some data here, same type;

  // bonus, you may want to check also that isLoading is initially false
  // expect(sut.isLoading).toBe(false);

  // check: after triggered, isLoading should be true until the subscription returns a value
  sut.ngOnOnit();
  expect(sut.isLoading).toBe(true);

  // check: after the subscription receives a value, isLoading should be false
  subject.next(mockData);
  expect(sut.isLoading).toBe(false);

  // bonus
  expect(sut.data).toEqual(mockData);
  expect(booksService.fetchData).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
....
it('should turn loading on when fetchBooks is called', () => {
  // notice we don't resolve bookService.fetchBooks in this case so
  // it doesn't go in the subscribe callback
  sut.fetchBooks();
  expect(sut.isLoading).toBe(true);
});

it('should turn loading off when bookService.fetchBooks resolves', () => {
  // make bookService.fetchBooks return instantaneously this time.
  spyOn(bookService, 'fetchBooks').and.returnValue(of({ data: [] }));
  sut.fetchBooks();
  expect(sut.isLoading).toBe(true);
  expect(sut.books).toEqual([]); // use toEqual here because toBe uses triple equality
                                 // and [] === [] returns false because it is comparing
                                 // locations in memory
});
```

***Edit***

I split up the test in two to make testing it easier.

The first test the observable (bookService.fetchBooks) does not return an observable so `this.isLoading = false` does not get traversed but the beginning of the function does so `this.isLoading = true` does. So basically this is testing the first half of the function is good, in essence `this.isLoading = true` happens before the observable "resolves" or emits.

The 2nd test resolves the observable immediately with `.returnValue(of({ data: [] }));` and so we test that loading gets turned off when the observable emits.

Comment: i am sorry but where do you test that `isLoading` is `true` but then switched to `false`?

Comment: Please explain _outside_ your code block how you're trying to achieve the question asked.

Comment: rel1x: I split one test in to two to make it easier. To do how you want to do it with one test would require adding a delay to the observables or messing around with time which can get complicated. @Roy I added an edit.